# How to make the x-axis values visible in a subplot with sharex=True after the axes below it has been deleted

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I created a subplot with multiple rows and columns and they share their x-axis.
After deleting the bottom right-most ax, the ax above it does not show the x-axis values. How can I make these x-axis values visible on this ax?

What I don't want, is to have to add the top right-most ax later on.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.delaxes(ax[1, 2])

plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

This is what I would like to get (this screenshot was altered in paint):
[image: This is what I would like to get]

I tried things like:

```
ax[0,2].xaxis.set_visible(True)
```

```
ax[0,2].set_xticks([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
```

```
ax[0,2].set_xticklabels([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
```

But none of these helped.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```
ax[0, 2].tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, do the subplots have to share the x-axis?

If not, you could do something like this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=False, sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout()

ax[0, 0].xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax[0, 1].xaxis.set_visible(False)
fig.delaxes(ax[1, 2])

plt.show()
```

If you do need the shared axis, maybe it's possible to move one plot to the bottom row?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout()

fig.delaxes(ax[0, 2])

plt.show()
```